# how to chose multiple elements from an array

Tags: python

sorry to even ask this super easy question lol.

i'm trying to give multiple inputs so that i can chose multiple elements in an array.

```
//creating a list of numbers 

max= int(input("how many numbers?"))
numbers = list(range(1, max+1))
print(numbers)

//by the input(n) printing n th element of the number and the one before it.
//for example numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
//n = 4
//output: 4,5 

while True:
    n = numbers[int(input())]
    if n == "E":
        break
    else:
        print(n-1, n)
```

what i'm trying to do is that i want to be able to select multiple n and see the results at once.

for example
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

n = 1, 4

output: 1,2,4,5

---

i've tried map and split but i failed since i'm not very familiar with python

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string, map them to integers and unpack them, and finally slice list:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> begin, end, *_ = map(int, input('Enter begin and end: ').split())
Enter begin and end: 1 4
>>> lst[begin-1:end]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Show my opeartions step by step:

```
>>> s = input('Enter begin and end: ')
Enter begin and end: 1 4
>>> s
'1 4'
>>> s.split()
['1', '4']
>>> list(map(int, ['1', '4']))
[1, 4]
>>> begin, end, *_ = 1, 4
>>> begin
1
>>> end
4
>>> _
[]
>>> lst[begin-1:end]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have `numbers` list in this case since it is always store value from 1 to max so we can assume `numbers[i] = i + 1`. Regarding multiple inputs, you can take them as string input split them by commas which can then be calculated individually inside the `for` loop

```
while True:
    numbers_str = input() # input: 1, 4
    if numbers_str == "E":
        break
    else:
        output = []
        for n_str in numbers_str.split(","):
            n = int(n_str)
            output += [n, n + 1]
        print(output) # output: [1, 2, 4, 5]
```